# Error after updating to angular 7. Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I upgraded my project from angular 6 to angular 7. I have a file upload component in my project. It gives a compiler error after the upgrade.

```
onUpload() {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = () => this.uploadFile(fileReader.result);
    fileReader.readAsText(this.fileToUpload);
}

uploadFile(fileContent: string) {
    //upload
}
```

In above code, `this.uploadFile(fileReader.result)` gives following error.

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'string'

The type of `fileReader.result` is `string | ArrayBuffer`, and it says this cannot be assigned to a `string`. How can I convert `string | ArrayBuffer` type to a `string`?

Comment: have you tried `fileReader.result as string` ?

Comment: @Zze it works. I didn't know about `as string`.  Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whilst `result` has the potential to return a string, it cannot implicitly cast this to a string as there is a risk of data loss. i.e. `ArrayBuffer as string` may result in data truncation (would have to test). So you have to explicitly cast it as to tell the compiler "I know what I am doing".

2 approaches to achieve this are:

```
(string)fileReader.result;
fileReader.result as string;
```

---

Folks, Check @Malvolio's answer, it's more complete.

Comment: Malvolio's answer is more correct. This is just hiding the issue under the rug. When it comes back to bite you, you'll be wondering why it's not working: it's not working because you're lying to TypeScript.

Answer (score 3):

You need a *typeguard*, like this:

```
if (this.fileToUpload instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
  // throw an error, 'cause you can't handle this
} else {
    fileReader.readAsText(this.fileToUpload);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method toString() to parse the result:

```
 const file = event.target.files[0];
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);

 const base64 = reader.result.toString().split(',')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fileReader.onload = () => this.uploadFile(<string>fileReader.result);
```